# TouchPad doesn't work on ASUS N552VX - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, touchpad, asus, synaptics

I have installed ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my Asus n552vx, but the touchpad is not recognized by the system. I have a dual boot, and in Windows all works fine. 
The xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04 and xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-16.04 packages are already installed.

This is the output of dpkg command:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Optical Mouse                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus Wireless Radio Control               id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD           id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

This is the output of xinput command:

```
Voluto=U (non noto)/I (installato)/R (rimosso)/P (rimosso totale)/H (in attesa)
| Stato=Non/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(nessuno)/R (reinstallazione richiesta) (Stato,Err: maiuscolo=grave)
||/ Nome                                   Versione               Architettura Descrizione
+++-======================================-======================-============-==========================================
ii  xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-16.04 1.9.0-1ubuntu1~16.04.1 amd64        Synaptics TouchPad driver for X.Org server
```

If I press fn + F9 anything changes.
Thanks for the help!